# Vue SPA - check if user is authenticated, redirect to login if not

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, vuex

I have a `VueJS` single-page application and I use JWT authentication.

I'm trying to figure out how to make sure that User is authenticated after page reload and if not, redirect them to login page.

`accessToken` and `refreshToken` are stored in the `cookies` and also in `Vuex`

Vuex.state:

```
auth: {
        user: {},
        isAuthenticated: false,
        accessToken: null,
        refreshToken: null
    },
```

Vuex.actions.refreshToken

```
    refreshToken: async ({state, commit, dispatch}) => {
        try {
            await api.jwtRefresh(state.auth.refreshToken).then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    dispatch("setAuthData",{
                        accessToken:response.data.access,
                        isAuthenticated:true
                    })
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                dispatch('logout')
            });
        } catch (e) {
            dispatch('logout')
        }
    },
```

App.vue

```
export default {
  data: () => ({}),
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setAuthDataFromCookies')
    this.$store.dispatch('refreshToken') // checks if user is authenticated, redirect to login page if not
    this.$router.push('/dashboard')
  }
}
```

My idea is to try to refresh the JWT token. If it was successfully refreshed User can proceed to `/dashboard`. If not, User is redirected to the `/login`

The problem is that `mounted` doesn't wait until `refreshToken` is done and it redirects User immediately to the `/dashboard` even before token is refreshed.

How can I make it wait? (The idea is that `refreshToken` will redirect user to `/login` in case of error.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a meta `auth` field in your router, and a global `beforeEnter` or `beforeEach` guard that checks Vuex (or your cookies, or both) for a token.

In your `router.js` file you'd have something like

```js
routes: [
  {
    name: 'Login'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dashboard', // + path, component, etc
    meta: {
      auth: true
    }
  }
]
```

Then you setup a global guard, something like this:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)) {
    if (!store.getters.authToken) {
      next({ name: 'Login' });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next(); // Very important to call next() in this case!
  }
})
```

This will check before each and every route transition whether the next route has the `auth` meta field. If it does, it checks your Vuex state for the token, and otherwise navigates as normally.

[Vue Router Docs on Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

In your case, you're trying to authenticate the user, so you can just call your endpoint inside of the `beforeEach` guard and redirect like that based on the response. Just make sure to make the callback asynchronous, like `router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {})`